# How to get 4-byte emojis to store correctly in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql

Only the 3 byte emojis are being stored correctly in my database.  Only the first byte of 4 byte emojis seem to be stored.  The result is a � being shown.

I've converted everything to utf8mb4 (database, tables, my.cnf etc).  It seems to only store the first byte in the database when I inspect it (no errors are thrown).  3 byte emojis seem to go in just fine.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+ 


update tweeters set name = 'Test Emoji ' where id=875198003409190912;

What actually shows in my console when I pasted in the emoji (Mojave terminal) 
update tweeters set name = 'Test Emoji �' where id=875198003409190912;
```

The only factor here besides me doing something wrong with database config is that my console doesn't seem to support 4 byte emojis either when I paste them in.  Even if that was the cause on the mysql console, I don't know how to fix my rails script to insert them correctly (I set the right encoding and collation there as well).

Comment: Have you added character_set for the column as well? Also what are you passing character_set=utf8mb4 with the connection string?

Comment: Hi Jeffy.  Just to eliminate it I installed MySQL Workbench and I was able to get the data in correctly.  There appears to be an issue with copying the emoji into the terminal.  When I copied the text from Workbench it came out like this     
`update tweeters set name = 'ad�\U+26ABd' where id  =875198003409190912;`

Which then worked as well.  Now I'm having trouble getting rails to display it correctly.  It shows the 3 byte emojis fine but not the 4 byte one that I finally got in.

Comment: Also figured out my rails issue...there was legacy code overriding the character encoding from database.yml.

Answer (score 2):

In the end it ended up being legacy code doing "SET NAMES UTF8" overriding the database.yml configuration.  Really macOS Mojave terminal was throwing me for a loop because it doesn't support the display of 4 byte emojis like the basketball and I assumed it was related to that.  Once I installed MySQL Workbench I could see that I was setting and retrieving the data correctly and then looked at my logs and saw the wrong set names being sent.